# Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

I'm using Python 3 typing feature for better autocomplete.

Many times I have functions that return key/value (dictionary) with specific keys. super simple example:

```py
def get_info(name):
    name_first_letter = name[0]
    return {'my_name': name, 'first_letter': name_first_letter}
```

I want to add type hinting to this function to tell others who use this function what to expect.

I can do something like:

```py
class NameInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, name, first_letter):
        self.name = name
        self.first_letter = first_letter
```

and then change the function signature to:

```py
def get_info(name) -> NameInfo:
```

But it requires too much code for each dictionary.

What is the best practice in that case?

Comment: Have you considered using `collections.namedtuple` to create your custom types? It does make only immutable types, but depending on how you were using the dictionaries before, that might not be an issue.

Comment: You can also try to use `Dict[str, str]` type hint from [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module.

Comment: @Blckknght  thanks for remind me this option.Found exactly what i need. There is type named tuple https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51031757/6646912

Comment: Related: [How to use static type checking using Dict with different value types in Python 3.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48013561/7851470)

Comment: This is a good use case for @attrs : https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/ .  Just define your object as an attrs-class and then `attr.asdict(name_info_pair)` will give you the desired dict

Comment: ..or, if you're on Python 3.7+ and don't want an external dependency on attrs, you can use [data classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#abstract).

Answer (score 114):

As pointed out by Blckknght, you and Stanislav Ivanov in the comments, you can use [`NamedTuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class NameInfo(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    first_letter: str


def get_info(name: str) -> NameInfo:
    return NameInfo(name=name, first_letter=name[0])
```

Starting from Python 3.8 you can use [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) which is more similar to what you want:

```
from typing import TypedDict


class NameInfo(TypedDict):
    name: str
    first_letter: str


def get_info(name: str) -> NameInfo:
    return {'name': name, 'first_letter': name[0]}
```

Comment: In this way you get some class-specific limitations, for example you can not pack your class using msgpack.

Comment: how to define, that NameInfo has key with service symbols, for example `last#name: str`?

Comment: @IvanBryzzhin You might try using [alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60003444/7851470).

Comment: This only works for str keys though

Comment: @Jerinaw you can, for the value, use `Literal` instead of `str` to give you a type hint support

Answer (score 12):

`TypedDict` can also be created using a typename and a dictionary where the keys are the keys and the values are the type of the values, respectively, of the dict to be returned by `get_info()`. This allows you to create keys that uses characters not in `A-Za-z0-9_`.

```py
from typing import TypedDict

NameInfo = TypedDict('NameInfo', {'name': str, 'first-letter': str})

def get_info(name: str) -> NameInfo:
    return {'name': name, 'first-letter': name[0]}

x = get_info('cottontail')
print(x['first-letter'])   # c
```

Then on PyCharm, the key hint is there (also works on jupyter notebook too by pressing tab).

[image: pycharm]