# How to use static type checking using Dict with different value types in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing, mypy

Trying to use static types in Python code, so `mypy` can help me with some hidden errors. It's quite simple to use with single variables

```
real_hour: int = lower_hour + hour_iterator
```

Harder to use it with lists and dictionaries, need to import additional `typing` library:

```
from typing import Dict, List
hour_dict: Dict[str, str] = {"test_key": "test_value"}
```

But the main problem - how to use it with Dicts with different value types, like:

```
hour_dict = {"test_key": "test_value", "test_keywords": ["test_1","test_2"]}
```

If I don't use static typing for such dictionaries - mypy shows me errors, like:

```
len(hour_dict['test_keywords'])
- Argument 1 to "len" has incompatible type
```

So, my question: how to add static types to such dictionaries? :)

Comment: [They're still working on that.](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/28)

Comment: If all of the types that the dict could contain are known, you could use `Union`. e.g. `Dict[str, Union[list, str]]`. However, this doesn't ensure that particular keys are always of a specified type, it just allows values to be either (e.g.) strings or lists.

Comment: (Also, it's `Dict[str, str]`, not `Dict[str:str]`.)

Comment: Related: [Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44225788/7851470)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need a `Union` type, of some sort.

```py
from typing import Dict, List, Union

# simple str values
hour_dict: Dict[str, str] = {"test_key": "test_value"}

# more complex values
hour_dict1: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = {
    "test_key": "test_value", 
    "test_keywords": ["test_1","test_2"]
}
```

In general, when you need an "either this or that," you need a `Union`. In this case, your options are `str` and `List[str]`.

There are several ways to play this out. You might, for example, want to define type names to simplify inline types.

```py
OneOrManyStrings = Union[str, List[str]]

hour_dict2: Dict[str, OneOrManyStrings] = {
    "test_key": "test_value", 
    "test_keywords": ["test_1","test_2"]
}
```

I might also advise for simplicity, parallelism, and regularity to make all your `dict` values pure `List[str]` even if there's only one item. This would allow you to always take the `len()` of a value, without prior type checking or guard conditions. But those points are nits and tweaks.

Comment: Additional question: how to use static typing with datetime objects?

Comment: @sortas Once a type is defined or imported, it can be used in typed Python just like a builtin such as `int` or `str`. So after `from datetime import datetime` you can just say `right_now: datetime = datetime.utcnow()`. Or you can use `datetime` in `Union`s or as the subtype of `List` and `Dict`, or otherwise used just as primitive types can be used.

Comment: Enuice Ok, understand, thanks. Still, mypy doesn't like Union: I define dict as `order_data: Dict[str, Union[str, int, List[str]]]`, but when I try to take data from it (`keywords_to_load: List[str] = order_data['keywords']`) mypy says "Incompatible types, expression has type `Union[str, int, List[str]]`, variable has type `List[str]`. Am I doing something wrong? I mean, it's not really a problem, still want to fix as may errors as possible :)

Comment: @sortas The problem is that mypy cannot *guarantee* the safety of that operation. Yes, it might be a `List[str]` value retrieved from `order_data['keywords']`. But it might equally be a `str` or an `int`. Mypy can't know, therefore it's not passing the checks. Try [something like this](https://gist.github.com/jonathaneunice/8a1bf79bd34a72da0f3c33504b481174) instead. That is a type equation mypy can guarantee.

Comment: when you use python 3.11, you can create a union easily by doing e. g. [str|int], so with the | character.

Answer (score 6):

While using `Union` is indeed one way of doing it, a more precise solution would be to use the (currently experimental) [`TypedDict`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#typeddict) type, which lets you assign specific types per each string key.

In order to use this type, you must first install the `mypy_extensions` 3rd party library using pip. You can then do the following:

```
from typing import List
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict

MyDictType = TypedDict('MyDictType', {
        'test_key': str, 
        'test_keywords': List[str],
})

hour_dict: MyDictType = {
    "test_key": "test_value", 
    "test_keywords": ["test_1","test_2"]
}
```

Note that we need to explicitly denote `hour_dict` of being of type `MyDictType`. A slightly cleaner way of doing this is to use `MyDictType` as a constructor -- at runtime, `MyDictType(...)` is exactly equivalent to doing `dict(...)`, which means the below code behaves exactly identically to the above:

```
hour_dict = MyDictType(
    test_key="test_value", 
    test_keywords=["test_1","test_2"]
)
```

Finally, note that there are a few limitations to using TypedDict:

1. It's useful only when the dict will contain specific keys with types that are all known at compile time -- you should use regular `Dict[...]` if you expect a truly dynamic dict.
2. The keys must all be strings.
3. At time being, this type is understood only by mypy (though I understand there are plans to eventually add TypedDict to PEP 484 once it's a little more battle-tested, which would mean any PEP 484 compliant typechecker would be required to support it).

(`TypedDict` was designed to make it easier to work with JSON blobs/dicts when writing serialization/deserialization logic, which is the reason for these constraints.)