# How to type hint a dictionary with values of different types

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, type-hinting, python-typing

When declaring a dictionary as a literal, is there a way to type-hint what value I am expecting for a specific key?

And then, for discussion: are there guiding principles around dictionary typing in Python? I'm wondering whether it is considered bad practice to mix types in dictionaries.

---

Here's an example:

Consider the declaration of a dictionary in a class's `__init__` :

*(Disclaimer: I realize in the example, some of the `.elements` entries would probably be more appropriate as class attributes, but it's for the sake of the example.)*

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, corners: Tuple[Tuple[float, float]], **kwargs):
        self.x, self.z = corners[0][0], corners[0][1]
        self.elements = {
            'front': Line(corners[0], corners[1]),
            'left': Line(corners[0], corners[2]),
            'right': Line(corners[1], corners[3]),
            'rear': Line(corners[3], corners[2]),
            'cog': calc_cog(corners),
            'area': calc_area(corners),
            'pins': None
        }


class Line:
    def __init__(self, p1: Tuple[float, float], p2: Tuple[float, float]):
        self.p1, self.p2 = p1, p2
        self.vertical = p1[0] == p2[0]
        self.horizontal = p1[1] == p2[1]
```

When I type type the following,

```
rec1 = Rectangle(rec1_corners, show=True, name='Nr1')
rec1.sides['f...
```

Pycharm will suggest `'front'`  for me. Better still, when I do

```
rec1.sides['front'].ver...
```

Pycharm will suggest `.vertical`

So Pycharm remembers the keys from the dictionary literal declaration in the class's `__init__`, and also their values' expected types. Or rather: it expects any value to have any one of the types that are in the literal declaration - probably the same as if I had done a `self.elements = {}  # type: Union[type1, type2]` would do. Either way, I find it super helpful.

If your functions have their outputs type-hinted, then Pycharm will also take that into account.

So assuming that in the `Rectangle` example above, I wanted to indicate that `pins` is a list of `Pin` objects... if `pins` was a normal class attribute, it would be:

```
    self.pins = None  # type: List[Pin]
```

(provided the necessary imports were done)

Is there a way to give the same type hint in the dictionary literal declaration?

The following does **not** achieve what I am looking for:

Add a `Union[...]` type hint at the end of the literal declaration?

```
            'area': calc_area(corners),
            'pins': None
        }  # type: Union[Line, Tuple[float, float], float, List[Pin]]
```

Adding a type-hint to every line:

```
            'area': calc_area(corners),  # type: float
            'pins': None  # type: List[Pin]
        }
```

Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

---

Some more background:

I work with Python in PyCharm and I make extensive use of typing, since it helps me to predict and validate my work as I go along. When I create new classes, I also sometimes throw some less frequently used properties into a dictionary to avoid cluttering the object with too many attributes (this is helpful in debug mode).

Comment: My unsolicited advice is that you should avoid doing this. It's not bad practice to mix types in python dictionaries. In fact, it is actually done quite frequently. It might seem wrong to do this coming from a strongly typed language but take advantage of this in python.

Comment: Thanks Skam. Why do you say I should avoid doing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easiest way:

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Movie(TypedDict):
   name: str
   year: int

movie: Movie = {'name': 'Blade Runner', 'year': 1982}

movie['year'] = '1982' # Error: invalid value type ("int" expected)
```

[TypedDict-PEP 589](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/#class-based-syntax)

Answer (score 20):

You are looking for [TypedDict](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict). It is currently only a mypy-only extension, but there are plans to [make it an officially sanctioned type](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5288) in the near-future. I am not sure if PyCharm supports this feature yet, though.

So, in your case, you'd do:

```
from mypy_extensions import TypedDict

RectangleElements = TypedDict('RectangleElements', {
    'front': Line,
    'left': Line,
    'right': Line,
    'rear': Line,
    'cog': float,
    'area': float,
    'pins': Optional[List[Pin]]
})

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, corners: Tuple[Tuple[float, float]], **kwargs):
        self.x, self.z = corners[0][0], corners[0][1]
        self.elements = {
            'front': Line(corners[0], corners[1]),
            'left': Line(corners[0], corners[2]),
            'right': Line(corners[1], corners[3]),
            'rear': Line(corners[3], corners[2]),
            'cog': calc_cog(corners),
            'area': calc_area(corners),
            'pins': None
        }  # type: RectangleElements
```

If you are using Python 3.6+, you can type this all more elegantly using the [class-based syntax](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#class-based-syntax).

In your specific case though, I think most people would just store those pieces of data as regular fields instead of a dict. I'm sure you've already thought through the pros and cons of that approach though, so I'll skip lecturing you about it.

Comment: [typing.TypeDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) entered standard library with Python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation, the best workaround I could find so far was to ensure the the class `Pin` could return some kind of a placeholder, and then use the placeholder as a value in the literal declaration.

therefore:

```
class Pin:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if len(kwargs) == 0:
            return
```

Now, in the example in the OP, I could do the following to achieve what I wanted:

```
        ...
        'area': calc_area(corners),
        'pins': List[Pin(),]
    }
```

However, if I had a basic type (or types) as a entries, this would not work.

```
        ...
        'area': calc_area(corners),
        'pins': List[Pin(),]
        'color': None
        'lap_times': None
    }
```

where 
`color` expects a string and
`lap_times` expects a list with floats...

In such a case the best work-around would be

```
        ...
        'area': calc_area(corners),
        'pins': List[Pin(),]
        'color': 'blue'
        'lap_times': [0.,]
    }

    self.elements['color'], self.elements['lap_times'] = None, None
```

Neither of these seems very elegant, so I am still hoping someone can suggest something better.