# How to do type casting for special datatypes in Python

Tags: python, variables, casting

I'm trying to determine the type of value in a dictionary which comes from a outside of a function sth like this;

```
def create_new_ds(sep_labels: dict, upper_limit: int, ds: bytearray, ref_lbl: str, rnd: bool) -> []:
    desired_lbls = sep_labels.keys()
    if rnd:
        sep_labels[ref_lbl]
```

in this code i know that value of this "sep_labels[ref_lbl]" dictionary is a pandas dataframe. Questions is how to let PyCharm IDE understand it to get its properties after putting comma.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint a dictionary with values of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51031757/how-to-type-hint-a-dictionary-with-values-of-different-types)

Comment: it seems little bit complicated. i'm gonna try it and let you know. Thanks

Comment: You could also try a [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead of a dict.

Comment: Type hinting is not the same as type casting. Type casting means converting from one type to another, like `intvar = int(stringvar)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  desired_lbls = sep_labels.keys()
  if rnd:
     pd_df : pd.DataFrame = sep_labels[ref_lbl]  # now pd_df is type casted(annotated)
     pd_df.DataFrame({'angles': [0, 3, 4],
                  'degrees': [360, 180, 360]},
                  index=['circle', 'triangle', 'rectangle'])
```

Python has a feature of variable annotation. If any variable cannot be determined in advance then it could be annotated whatever type you want by putting colon(:) after name of variable as done above.