# Typing hinting nested dictionary with varying value types

Tags: python, mypy

My dictionary looks as follows:

```
spreadsheet_list: dict[str, dict[str, Union[str, list[str]]]] = {
    'final_kpis': {
        'gsheet_key': '1np6fM9d_BrBuDbBKWkWwUjhNypoCtto_84bLcx-HBdk', 
        'primary_key': ['KPI_Reference']
    },
    'maplecroft_risk_drivers': {
        'gsheet_key': '1rV2oXbvvXcq6glLpHu1X4e_huR4mkZ4bbcZ2cQPv_A0', 
        'primary_key': ['Commodity_type', 'Commodity', 'Country']
    }
}
```

I am looping over the dict with:

```
for name, info in spreadsheet_list.items():
    do_stuff(name, info['gsheet_key'], info['primary_key'])
```

Where the expected types are specified in the function args:

```
def do_stuff(name: str, gsheet_key: str, primary_key: list[str]):
```

Error returned is:

```
error: Argument 2 to "do_stuff" has incompatible type "str | list[str]"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
error: Argument 3 to "do_stuff" has incompatible type "str | list[str]"; expected "list[str]"  [arg-type]
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74287279/5392289) solution using `TypedDict`, but not for a nested dictionary.

Comment: Couldn't you use a TypedDict as your inner dictionary?
So the signature of your top-level dict would become: 
`Dict[str, YourTypedDict]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem with using a `TypedDict` instead of a `dict[str, Union[str, list[str]]]`?

```py
import typing

def do_stuff(name: str, gsheet_key: str, primary_key: list[str]):
    pass

class InnerDict(typing.TypedDict):
    gsheet_key: str
    primary_key: list[str]

spreadsheet_list: dict[str, InnerDict] = {
    'final_kpis': {
        'gsheet_key': '1np6fM9d_BrBuDbBKWkWwUjhNypoCtto_84bLcx-HBdk', 
        'primary_key': ['KPI_Reference']
    },
    'maplecroft_risk_drivers': {
        'gsheet_key': '1rV2oXbvvXcq6glLpHu1X4e_huR4mkZ4bbcZ2cQPv_A0', 
        'primary_key': ['Commodity_type', 'Commodity', 'Country']
    }
}

for name, info in spreadsheet_list.items():
    do_stuff(name, info['gsheet_key'], info['primary_key'])
```