# TypedDict when keys have invalid names

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, typing

If I have a key in a dictionary with an invalid identifier, such as `A(2)`. How can I create a `TypedDict` with this field?

E.g

```
from typing import TypedDict

class RandomAlphabet(TypedDict):
    A(2): str
```

is not valid Python code, resulting in the error:

```
SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation
```

The same problem is with reserved keywords:

```
class RandomAlphabet(TypedDict):
    return: str
```

throws:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

According to [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589) you can use [alternative syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax) to create a `TypedDict` as follows:

> `Movie = TypedDict('Movie', {'name': str, 'year': int})`

So, in your case, you could write:

```
from typing import TypedDict

RandomAlphabet = TypedDict('RandomAlphabet', {'A(2)': str})
```

or for the second example:

```
RandomAlphabet = TypedDict('RandomAlphabet', {'return': str})
```

---

[PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax) warns, though:

> This syntax doesn't support inheritance, however, and there is no way
> to have both required and non-required fields in a single type. The
> motivation for this is keeping the backwards compatible syntax as
> simple as possible while covering the most common use cases.

Comment: It's good to know I was on the right lines but I was really hoping there would be a better method than this - a class syntax that breaks if a single key has a hyphen in it is far from ideal! I was hoping from something like dataclass' fields.

Comment: @TomDufall I suppose that could be proposed in a future PEP. Backwards compatibility isn't impacted if it's a feature only new code would have. I'd like it.

Comment: This works with typechecking in Pycharm like a charm!

Answer (score 9):

This is fairly messy, but it works if you need inheritance.

```py
class RandomAlphabet(
    TypedDict(
        "RandomAlphabet",
        {"A(2)": str, "return": str},
    ),
    SomeInheritedTypedDict,
):
    pass
```

You can also replace `pass` with other normal properties that don't use invalid identifiers or reserved keywords if you have any.

Comment: That's the way I just did it right now and was hoping I wasn't doing something wrong