# How to make a TypedDict with integer keys?

Tags: python-3.x, integer, type-hinting, typeddict

Is it possible to use an integer key with TypedDict (similar to dict?).

Trying a simple example:

```py
    from typing import TypedDict 
    
    class Moves(TypedDict):
      0: int=1
      1: int=2
```

Throws: `SyntaxError: illegal target for annotation`

It seems as though only `Mapping[str, int]` is supported but I wanted to confirm. It wasn't specifically stated in the [Pep docs.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/)

Comment: You can't, in the class-based syntax. Identifiers can't start with a number. Use https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax instead.

Comment: What's the pattern of the numeric keys? A `list[int]` may be more appropriate if the keys are contiguous (the indices would be the key).

Comment: @Carcigenicate that makes sense. I'd like to know the answer all the same though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypedDict when keys have invalid names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003444/typeddict-when-keys-have-invalid-names)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent of `TypedDict` is explicit in [the PEP's abstract](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#abstract) (emphasis added):

> This PEP proposes a type constructor `typing.TypedDict` to support the use case where a dictionary object has *a specific set of string keys*, each with a value of a specific type.

and given the intended use cases are all annotatable in class syntax, implicitly applies only to `dict`s keyed by strings that constitute valid identifiers (things you could use as attribute or keyword argument names), not even strings in general. So as intended, `int` keys aren't a thing, this is just for enabling a class that uses `dict`-like syntax to access the "attributes" rather than attribute access syntax.

While [the alternative, backwards compatible syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#alternative-syntax), allowed for compatibility with pre-3.6 Python, allows this (as well as allowing strings that aren't valid Python identifiers), e.g.:

```
Moves = TypedDict('Moves', {0: int, 1: int})
```

you could only construct it with `dict` literals (e.g. `Moves({0: 123, 1: 456})`) because the cleaner keyword syntax like `Moves(0=123, 1=456)` doesn't work. And even though that technically works at runtime (it's all just `dict`s under the hood after all), the actual type-checkers that validate your type correctness may not support it (because the intent and documented use exclusively handles strings that constitute valid identifiers).

Point is, don't do this. For the simple case you're describing here (consecutive integer integer "keys" starting from zero, where each position has independent meaning, where they may or may not differ by type), you really just want a `tuple` anyway:

```
Moves = typing.Tuple[int, int]  # Could be [int, str] if index 1 should be a string
```

would be used for annotations the same way, and your actual point of use in the code would just be normal `tuple` syntax (`return 1, 2`).

If you really want to be able to use the name `Moves` when creating instances, on 3.9+ you could use [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/) to do (no import required):

```
Moves = tuple[int, int]
```

allowing you to write:

```
return Moves((1, 2))
```

when you want to make an "instance" of it. No runtime checking is involved (it's roughly equivalent to running `tuple((1, 2))` at runtime), but static type-checkers should understand the intent.