# How to define a TypedDict class with keys containing hyphens

Tags: python, python-typing, typing

How can I create a TypedDict class that supports keys containing hyphens or other characters that are supported in strings, such as "justify-content" in the example below.

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Literal
from typing_extensions import NotRequired

class Attributes(TypedDict):
    width: NotRequired[str]
    height: NotRequired[str]
    direction: NotRequired[Literal["row", "column"]]
    justify-content: NotRequired[Literal["start", "end", "center", "equally-spaced"]]
```

Comment: hyphens are disallowed from variable names in TypeDict AFAIK

Comment: Thank you for your comment @HimanshuPoddar. I would really like the keys of this dictionary to contain hyphens, is there any other options for creating a good type hint for it? Or will I have to translate hyphens in the dictionary keys to underscores...

Comment: AFAIK there is no such way, you ll have to use `_`. But only python experts can tell us here if there exists a workaround for this!

Comment: Actually you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60005869/10909029)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with the functional syntax:

```py
from typing import TypedDict, Literal
from typing_extensions import NotRequired


Attributes = TypedDict(
    "Attributes",
    {
        "width": NotRequired[
            str,
        ],
        "height": NotRequired[
            str,
        ],
        "direction": NotRequired[
            Literal["row", "column"],
        ],
        "justify-content": NotRequired[
            Literal["start", "end", "center", "equally-spaced"]
        ],
    },
)
```

It's mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)

> The functional syntax should also be used when any of the keys are not valid identifiers, for example because they are keywords or contain hyphens