# How to tell mypy about a complex type for a specific item in a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from typing import Dict, Union, Any, cast, Callable

some_variable = {'aaa': '123', 'zzz': 1}  # type: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]

# ensure that some_variable['zzz'] is an int
some_variable['zzz'] = int(some_variable['zzz'])

sleep_time = some_variable['zzz']  # type: int

time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

Clearly, by the time `sleep_time` is defined, the type of `some_variable['zzz']` is an `int`.
Yet, mypy gives an `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[str, int]", variable has type "int")`.

My questions is: **how to tell mypy that the type is `int` at that point in the code?** And better: **how to tell mypy that the type is some complex data structure at that point in the code?**

Notes:

1. As far as I know, there is no way to tell mypy about the data structure for a specific key in `dict` during initialization of the dict, so I like to tell mypy about the structure when I process it. That's what I try to do with `sleep_time = some_variable['zzz']  # type: int`.
2. `assert isinstance(some_variable['zzz'], int)` does suppress the error. Unfortunately, I can't use `isinstance`, since the actual data type in my code is not an int, but more complex data structure. Adding a line `some_variable['zzz'] = cast(int, some_variable['zzz'])` or `some_variable['zzz'] = int(some_variable['zzz'])` does not seem to make a difference to mypy. That's too bad, as cast() can take complex data structures, and I can define a complex data structure as the output of a type coercion function.
3. To my surprise, `some_variable = {'aaa': '123', 'zzz': 1}  # type: Dict[str, Any]` (thus with `Any` instead of `Union[str,int]`) silences any errors by mypy.
4. Adding `type: int` to the line `some_variable['zzz'] = int(some_variable['zzz'])` gives an error: `Unexpected type declaration`.
5. FYI, my actual codes is more akin to the following, where `some_variable` is read from file, but with more complex normalisation functions than `str.lower()` and `int()`.

```
mappers = {
    'aaa': str.lower,
    'zzz': int
}  # type: Dict[str, Callable[[Any], Union[str, int]]]
defaults = {
    'aaa': '',
    'zzz': 2
}  # type: Dict[str, Union[str, int]]
for key, value in some_variable.items():
    try:
        some_variable[key] = mappers[key](value)
    except Exception:
        some_variable[key] = defaults[key]
```

Comment: Can you use [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict)?

Comment: @Georgy thanks, good suggestion. Feel free to turn this into an answer. Note that is only available starting with Python 3.8 (for other reasons I like to be backward compatible with 3.7, but perhaps I can make mypy work with 3.8, and the running code with 3.7)

Comment: Hmm... If the `TypedDict` is what you are looking for, then, I guess, the question should be closed as a duplicate of [Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44225788/7851470). I'll leave it to subject matter experts, though.

Comment: No, TypedDict is a workaround at best. What I'm looking for is https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#redefinitions-with-incompatible-types ("How to redefine a variable with a more precise or a more concrete type") Given that it is the manual, it should work. I just failed to see why it throws an error in my code above.