# typing Dict with multiple key value types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing

I have a python function which returns a dictionary with the following structure

```
{
   (int, int): {string: {string: int, string: float}}
}
```

I am wondering how I can specify this with type hints. So, these bits are clear:

```
Dict[Tuple[int, int], Dict[str, Dict[str, # what comes here]]
```

However, the internal dictionary has `int` and `float` value types for the two keys. I am not sure how to annotate that

Comment: As far as I know, the only way to do this properly is with a TypedDict. Have you had a look at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/?

Comment: Duplicate for fixed keys: [Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44225788/7851470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

> Union type; `Union[X, Y]` means either X or Y.

```
from typing import Union

Dict[Tuple[int, int], Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[int, float]]]
```

That being said, it might be a better idea to use a `tuple` or a `namedtuple` in place of the inner `dict` if the keys are always the same.

Comment: Union here would mean int and float are accepted on all fields. If it is important to differentiate which keys accept int and which accept float then this would be too general. Granted though, OP didn't make that distinction in his question

Comment: @Karl True. In that case your `TypedDict` suggestion makes more sense.

Comment: I will investigate this `TypedDict` think as the structur of the Dict is fixed