# Python function return type hints with fixed dictionary keys

Tags: python-3.x, key, type-hinting, python-3.10

I have a function which returns a dictionary that always has the same keys (send over network and "stringified" with json). And basically my function looks like this:

```
def getTemps(self) -> dict:
    """
    get room and cpu temperature in °C as well as humidity in %
    """
    # send temperature request to server
    msg = {'type':'req', 'reqType':'temps'}
    self.send(msg)

    res = self.recieve()    # get response

    return res
```

and the dictionary you get from this function always looks something like that:

```
{'Room':float, 'CPU':float, 'hum':float}
```

so I was wondering if there was a way to specify the return type of the function so you know what keys the dictionary has:

```
def getTemps(self) -> Dict['Room':float, 'CPU':float, 'hum':float]
```

but that didn't work as it only showed `Dict[slice, slice, slice]` when hovering over the function (I am using vscode).

I don't think this is something that is very useful, but something that makes your code look better and also be easier to use for someone else. So if someone knows if this is possible and how, I would be very grateful to get a response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225788/python-3-dictionary-with-known-keys-typing)

Answer (score 0):

consider this:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self,room,cpu,hum):
        self.Room = room
        self.CPU = cpu
        self.hum = hum
```

and `return Message(room,cpu,hum)` or define a method to convert this to `dict` in the class if necessary.

This may be the only method.

Update: This is neither the only nor the best method, see comments.

Comment: This is not the only, or the best, method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198204/13990016