# How to specify a return type for dictionary keys in Python?

Tags: python

**Given a function that I want to enhance using type hinting (in Python 3.9)**:

```py
def my_func():
    return my_dict.keys() # origin of my_dict is irrelevant
```

I've seen [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) and [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54198204/9655481) describing how to type the keys and values in a dict using `TypedDict`. However, this is *not* what I try to achieve.

I want a return type for the dictionary keys object. I know [one can convert the keys object into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16819250/9655481) using `list(my_dict)` and then use the return type `list[key_type]` (with `key_type` being `int`, `str` etc.). But is this the way to go?

### Type of `my_dict`

```py
>>> type(my_dict.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

However, I was not able to use `dict_keys` like this:

```py
def my_func() -> dict_keys:
     return my_dict.keys()
```

Pylance reports that `my_dict.keys()` is of type `_dict_keys[key_type, value_type]`. Why is this type supposed to be "private" and where is it coming from? Can we somehow use it as return type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Python 3.9, you can `KeysView` from the `collections` module to type hint your function:

```
from collections import KeysView

d = {'1': 1}


def keys(d: dict[str, int]) -> KeysView[str]:
    return d.keys()
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.KeysView

For older versions, use `typing.KeysView` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem . Note that we can also use `dict` directly in `Python 3.9`, not `Dict[...]` (see [PEP 585](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0585/)), just to improve this answer ;)